# Is there a row_to_json equivilant for XML?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to do something similar to:

```
UPDATE <table> SET someColumn = row_to_json(<table>);
```

Or `INSERT Into <table>  Select row_to_json(<table>)`, but essentially the goal is convert the entire row to XML and add that XML to a separate column, row by row.

Is it something like this possible with Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write one that uses JSONB as an intermediate representation to extract the column names from an anonymous record parameter

One way to do it, is to generate a result similar to `query_to_xml()`

```
create function row_to_xml(p_row record)
  returns xml
as
$$
declare
  l_result xml;
begin  
  select xmlagg(xmlelement(name "column", xmlattributes(key as name), value))
    into l_result
  from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(p_row));
  return l_result;
end;  
$$
language plpgsql
immutable
parallel safe;
```

The above returns something like `<column name="id">42</column>` which is a bit verbose, but the XML tagname can't be a variable when using `xmlelement()`

Another option is to generate the XML manually:

```
create function row_to_xml(p_row record)
  returns xml
as
$$
declare
  l_result xml;
begin  
  select xmlagg(concat('<', key, '>', value, '</', key, '>')::xml)
    into l_result
  from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(p_row));
  return l_result;
end;  
$$
language plpgsql
immutable
parallel safe;
```

Note that for the above, you will need to write a function that properly escapes the values to replace the characters `<`, `>` , `&` and `"`. Or wrap the entire value in a `CDATA` section.

If you want to exclude columns with NULL values, you can extend it to use `jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(p_row))`

Either version can be used by passing a table reference:

```
select row_to_xml(t)
from the_table t;
```

Comment: This is really interesting, I haven't used pgsql functions much but when I blindly copy paste I get the error "pgSQL functions cannot accept type record" does that mean p_row is not a valid input  parameter type?

Comment: @cnorris: then you are using an older version. It works just fine in 11 and later: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=85f4a9e1ff0872305c3876279bf255d2

Comment: Of course you're completely right. Works like a charm, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xmlforest`:

```sql
TABLE local;

 id | val 
----+-----
  1 | one
  2 | two
(2 rows)

SELECT xmlforest(id, val) FROM local;

        xmlforest         
--------------------------
 <id>1</id><val>one</val>
 <id>2</id><val>two</val>
(2 rows)
```

Different from `row_to_json`, you will have to name the table columns, but that is the best you get. If you need to have a generic solution that works for all tables, you will have to use a dynamic SQL statement constructed from `information_schema.columns`.